# Push a string and display in a UITextField

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, uisplitviewcontroller

I am doing a small app and I am using a UISplitVIewController and I am trying to push the UITable cell text to the detail view and display it in a UITextField. I have managed to push the string nicely when i test it with a NSLog but when i apply to the UITextField it does not display not sure why here my method: (I am doing this using a storyboard)

```
-(void)pushModuleName:(NSString*)moduleName
{
    self.Lv4ModuleTitleTextField.text = moduleName;
    NSLog(@"name pushed%@",moduleName);
}
```

Not sure why this doesn't work.

[UPDATE]

UITableViewController.m (where the method is called)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *selectedModule = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_numberOfRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    Lv4GradeViewController *lv4 = [[Lv4GradeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [lv4 pushModuleName:selectedModule];

}
```

Comment: Have you verified that `self.Lv4ModuleTitleTextField` is not `nil`?

Comment: @rmaddy No where should I do this

Comment: In your `pushModuleName:` method.

Comment: @rmaddy I don't see how that would make a difference though

Comment: In your `pushModuleName:` method, log `self.Lv4ModuleTitleTextField`. Most likely you never properly set this property so your call to set its text doesn't do anything.

Comment: @rmaddy could u give me a snippet pls

Comment: Really? Just use `NSLog(@"self.Lv4ModuleTitleTextField = %@", self.Lv4ModuleTitleTextField);`

Comment: @rmaddy Oh right yeah it is null but I dont understand why what am I missing

Comment: Are you using Interface Builder? You probably didn't assign the text field to the outlet.

Comment: @rmaddy I have this in the .h property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *Lv4ModuleTitleTextField;

Comment: You need to give some context. Which controller is the code you posted in? How is it called, and from where? Please edit your question to show the calling method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not getting a reference to the Lv4GradeViewController that you have on screen, you're creating a new one with alloc init. A split view controller, has a viewControllers array, with the controller at index 0 being the master controller, and the one at index 1 being the detail controller. So, the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method should look like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *selectedModule = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_numberOfRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    Lv4GradeViewController *lv4 = self.splitViewController.viewControllers[1];
    [lv4 pushModuleName:selectedModule];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new instance of Lv4GradeViewController with the following code but no XIB file which will contain the text field:

```
Lv4GradeViewController *lv4 = [[Lv4GradeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

I would suggest you instantiate Lv4GradeViewController with the storyboard `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` method:

```
Lv4GradeViewController *lv4 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IdentifierName"];
```

And remember to set the storyboard ID of the Lv4GradeViewController the same as *IdentifierName* in the storyboard.

[image: Set the storyboard ID of the view controller]

Comment: I have linked my textfield ans synthesized it but it just doesn set the text i have no idea why

Comment: What should the IdentifierName be

Comment: @oneArled: it can be anything you want, but you need to set it in the storyboard. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I did that but my textfield still returns null I dont understand

Comment: This is incorrect. The detail view controller is already instantiated when the split view controller is, so you just need to get a reference to it, not create another one.